# Outlook Add-in Delegate Access to Calendar

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-app, outlook-2016

For an Outlook add-in using add-in commands (office.js), the ribbon buttons under the AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface extension point are disabled when creating a meeting in Outlook 2016 in a calendar for which the user has been granted delegate access.

The same add-in running under OWA is able to operate on the delegated calendar with no issues.

Is this a bug with Outlook 2016 or is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Note that for Outlook 2016 when the meeting compose view is open for the delegated calendar, the generic "Office Add-ins" ribbon button is also disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegated Mailboxs/Items are not supported by Outlook Add-ins at this time.

If you would like to request this feature, please do so through UserVoice:

https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/284136-outlook-com/category/132039-add-ins

Comment: Our add-in commands appear to work in OWA for operating on a delegated calendar. Is this an unintended feature? Is this just not supported for add-ins running on Outlook 2013 and 2016?

Comment: @Carbo Yes, this is unintended. Add-ins are not officially supported in Delegate Access scenarios (both Mail and Calendar) in all versions of OWA and Outlook.